# Route process output to windbg

Tags: debugging, winapi, monitoring, windbg

Working on virtual machine environment, I'm using `DbgView` to obtain my printout log messages using `debug_wsting`

However, Working on large number of processes that produces those messages seem to consume lot to cpu and eventually halt the VM, So I'm looking of a way to offload this activity to the machine that runs this VM. 
Perhaps there's a way to output the logs to remote `windbg` ?

Is there anything to configure on Client/Server ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it on my own, but it's described in [Windows Sysinternals Administrator's reference (Amazon)](https://www.amazon.de/dp/073565672X). I thought I knew the Sysinternals tools quite well, but it turned aout I learned a lot. Totally worth reading.

> To perform remote monitoring, DebugView runs in agent mode on the remote system [...]

To do so, run `DbgView /a`. Add `/k` if you need kernel messages as well and `/g`for session 0.

> [...] sending debug output it captures to a central DebugView viewer that displays the output.

and

> To begin remote monitoring, press Ctrl+R or choose Connect from the Computer menu [...]
>
> Be careful not to connect multiple viewers to a single computer because the debug output will be split between those viewers.

So, the output is there only once and after whatever machine fetches it, it's gone. Sounds normal.